# Selecting <p> elements that have not text nodes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure:

```
<div class="article-body">
<p>
    <a href="http://www.example.com">My Link</a>
Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit amet.

</p>
<p><a href="http://www.example.com">Link that I must select.</a></p>
</div>​
```

and I must apply a class to the second link, the one without text nodes. I tried "p:empty a" and "p > a:only-child" but they don't work... There is a way to select it using jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can't do with selector, but you can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to perform custom selection:

```
$('p').filter(function(){
    var $clone = $(this).clone();
    $clone.children().remove();
    return !$clone.text();
}).addClass("red");​
```

Here, have a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adrianonantua/5daYT/

:)

**Update**

As per @dfsq suggestion, we can take advantage of [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/) and make this same logic in one line:

```
$('p').filter(function(){
    return !$(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
}).addClass("red");​
```

Comment: +1. Can be made in one line: `return !$(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();`

Comment: @dfsq That's nice! I'll add this to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$("p").filter(function() {
    return $(this).contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim(this.nodeValue) != "";
    }).length == 0;
}).addClass("myClass")​;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/wyvLC/

Comment: .contents will also get text nodes of the `a` won't it? Edit: Guess not.. demo works,

Answer (score 3):

This will be a very fast solution. No cloning needed:

```
$("p > a").filter(function(i, el) {
    return !el.previousSibling && !el.nextSibling;
}).parent();
```

---

Or this:

```
$("p").filter(function(i, el) {
    return el.firstChild && 
           el.firstChild === el.lastChild && 
           el.firstChild.nodeName.toUpperCase() === "A";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work http://jsfiddle.net/nvass/ :

```
$("p").filter(function(){
    return $.grep(this.childNodes,function(node){
         return node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue.replace(/(\s|\n|\r|\t)/g,"") !== "";
    }).length === 0;
}).css("background-color","green");
```

Comment: even emptyText corresponds to nodeType 3 right .. So if the p tag has empty text nodes then this won't work right ??

Comment: @Sushanth-- Right. in that case i also need to test the nodevalue.

Comment: @VisioN I never realized exactly what .contents is doing. It is literally doing `this.childNodes` if `this` isn't an iframe or window.

Comment: cool I think that does it .. Also I have a question regarding the empty Text nodes.. How do we test if the Empty Text is a new line..  I try checking $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== ""  for such cases and it never works for me

Comment: @Sushanth-- String.prototype.trim only removes leading and ending spaces, it does not remove tabs or linebreaks. jQuery's $.trim by default simply uses the built-in String.prototype.trim if available. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: kevin ..sure.. that was helpful.. So how do we go about filtering line breaks and new lines...  Will $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== "\n" && $.trim(this.nodeValue) !== "\n" do

Comment: @Sushanth-- It would probably be better to tack on a .match .test or .replace to remove linebreaks and tabs. `$.trim(this.nodeValue).replace(/(\n|\r|\t)/g,"")` or just replace $.trim all together.

Comment: @KevinB ..  I will try that out.. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Looks like it handles all the conditions now o)

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use a one-liner: `$("p").filter(function(){ return $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text() == ""; });​`...

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bJnEJ/1/

Source (adapted): http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/

Comment: Was it necessary to make an answer for condensing someone else's answer after suggesting it to them?

Comment: You took Adrian's code, made it a one-liner, told them, and then posted as an answer. Your comment was enough, as all it did was "improve" the original answer.

Comment: That was not my comment and I found this answer _before_ that comment, to "prove" it I posted my source.